# Is it Possible to edit a third party app in Android studio?

Tags: android

My problem is there is a set of apps called good lock apps made by Samsung But they aren't supported by One UI core devices and some, not with android 11, So I would like to increase the API level of the application, add any android source code as well as somehow make it accessible by one UI core devices(By changing boolean).In Android studio, I tried the above but the code reverts back to the original, and am not able to run it, So can someone please say if the above is possible, if possible say how to proceed and if not please say what can be done alternatively, Thank you!

Comment: Is `good lock apps` a system application?

Comment: No its a  third party application made by Samsung

Answer (score 0):

If it's a third party application, then the app would reside within data partition. And in any case you should be able to install the new version of a third party app unless you hold version number higher than the one present in the device.

While targeting SDK version higher than 25 make sure that you have [REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) to install a new application.

The other option is to uninstall the existing application (at your own risk), and reinstall the compiled version of the apk.

If you still face issues, please attach the logcat information while installing the apk, that could help us to look into the problem further.